# How to specify BasicHttpBinding with Savon (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, basichttpbinding, savon

Im getting this error:

> (a:6016) The message with Action 'xxx'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver,
>   due to a ContractFilter mismatch at
>   the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and
>   receiver) or a binding/security
>   mismatch between the sender and the
>   receiver.  Check that sender and
>   receiver have the same contract and
>   the same binding (including security
>   requirements, e.g. Message, Transport,
>   None).

And I noticed that the binding used by my provider's WSDL is:

BasicHttpBinding_IxFlow

I guess I need to specify that in my Savon Controller. How can I do that?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message is not really helpful (received this one for various errors) here are some suggestions:

- try calling the service (or just generate the xml) from another client and record the XML
- compare with Savonrb XML (it prints it to the console, not pretty formatted but good enough)
- send the XML you captured from another client trough savon. Does this work? (you can specify custom XML with the block version of client#request method)
- Look at (this was the problem with my service):

  - Order of parameters
  - Namespace of parameters
  - SOAPAction header (you can also specify it in the block version)